# How to recover password protected power-point?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, password-recovery

I have a powerpoint file which was written using MS Office PowerPoint 2007.

When I click on my `.ppt` it's asking for password. I forgot my password I used to open my `.ppt` file.

I'm using PowerPoint 2013 now.

Comment: If you are using 2013 then check the information in link below http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2013/01/25/now-you-can-reset-or-remove-a-password-from-a-word-excel-or-powerpoint-file-with-office-2013.aspx (or) You can find several ppt password crackers in google add one sample link for you. Select the one that fits you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNl66ZAjnAc Hope this helps

Comment: It was created using MS Office 2007 and i have never opened it on MS OFFICE 2013 . So it will not work . I don't want to pay for pass word recovery.

Comment: DoCrypt can only be used for the files created after installing DoCrypt . You cannot open the files which were created and encrypted before installing Docrypt .

Comment: If the encryption algorithm is at all good you're SOL.

Comment: @DanielRHicks This question is of no use since its that secure ..